# urlencode php example

Tags: php

I want to pass a php variable as part of the link. How can I achieve this?

```
$x = 24; //$x is a php variable
```

How to pass this value as part of a href="". A working example would be helpful.

Comment: Please use more words. You'll have to specify if you want to pass the value stored in the variable, or whether you want to pass the variable itself. Given the title `urlencode` php example, I'm lead to believe you've got the wrong idea of what `urlencode` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<A href="whatever.php?x=<php echo $x;?>">link</a>
```

Comment: This'll fail if `$x` has special characters like ampersands.

Comment: x is 24.  So it wasn't a case i was worried about.  He said url_encode because he didn't know what it did.  Not because he actually needed something encoded.  For what i believe he wants, my answer is the clearest and most simple. But thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It works mostly like the version you know from Javascript:

```
print '<a href="page.php?x=' . urlencode($x) . '&y=2">click here</a>';
```

Or if you want to use the PHP inline html notation style (with short tags `<?=` enabled):

```
<p><a href="page.php?x=<?= urlencode($x) ?>">click here</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = 24;
$y = 'some text';
print('<a href="http://site.com/url.php?x=' . rawurlencode($x) . '&amp;y=' . rawurlencode($y) . '"></a>');
```

in url.php file you can get this variables using

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`http_build_query()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build query string (`a=b&c=d`). This function handles all typical probles like escaping (eg. `#` → `%23`) or proper HTML mark-up (`&` → `&amp;`) etc.

```
printf('<a href="http://site.com/url.php?%s">Click me</a>', http_build_query(array(
   'a' => $x,
   'b' => 'Some strange characters like #$^$%&%^*^&('
)));
```